# Using i from "for loop" as part of variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the "i" value as part of already declared variable, and then use the int value of that variable.

I found how to format output to a string, but that doesn't help me, since I need the int value of variable "place(i)".

I made simplified version of my code:

```
    int place0 = 3;
    int place1 = 0;
    int place2 = -3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i+1 == 3)
            {
            int yPos = place[i];        //?
            int yPos = place + i;       //?
            int yPos = string.Format("place{0}", i);    //?

            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 1);
            }
    }
```

In this case variable "yPos" should be set to value of "place2", which is -3. But I'm struggling to pass the variable value instead of variable name.

I know there must be a simple solution to this, but it's over my head. I'm also having trouble defining this problem, and therefore finding and answer.

Comment: You should read up on **arrays**, and after that, the `List` class.

Comment: Why `if (i + 1 == 3)` and not just `if (i == 2)`? Did you mean `if (i < 3)` instead?

Comment: You should use i+1 = 3. You cant use == for int, because it is not a bool.

Comment: It appears there's no need for your `for` loop to go from `0` to `9` when you only care about values `0` to `2`.

Comment: The "i+1==3" was for the sake of simplicity, I'm using entirely different statements in my real code. Thank you for the answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right syntax to use the data structure with this line:

```
int yPos = place[i];
```

It's just not the right data structure yet.  What you're looking for is an array.  Something like this:

```
int[] place = new int[] { 3, 0, -3 };
```

Another step forward would likely be to use a `List<>`, which can be a bit more forgiving and more flexible than a standard array:

```
List<int> place = new List<int> { 3, 0, -3 };
```

In either case I'd also recommend renaming `place` to `places`, just for the semantics of plurality.

Overall, whether we're talking about a `List<>`, a `Dictionary<>`, or any other kind of collection, in general any time you find yourself wanting to number a series of variables what you're *probably* looking for is a collection.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to store your values in an array or a list, which can then be accessed by index:

```
int[] places = {3, 0, -3};

for (int i = 0; i < places.Length; i++)
{
    int yPos = places[i];
    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 1);
}
```